# how do I link to a page with a specific filter chosen?

Tags: javascript, html

http://gazwan.info/
this is the page

I want to link to the packaging section, but it's not a url, is there a way to create a link that would get the pge with the packaging option clicked?

Comment: Please post the actual code not a link to some other site.  If that site changes, this question then becomes useless

Answer (score 0):

> Without URL query you cant do this

Try like this

pass some url query like `http://gazwan.info/#packaging` .Then  validate url via  js code in `gazwan.info` website

```
var q = window.location.hash.replace('#','').trim();

$('span[data-id="'+q+'"]').trigger('click');
//or
//do with packaging clicking event
```

Comment: I can edit the page where the link originates from, but the gazwan.info page is a wordpress theme that I have no idea how to edit ro whether that's possible at all

Comment: I think its no other way .Better add little bit js code in your WordPress.Check with web `how to add custom js in wordpress` more num of the solution is there.Surely they will help you to add a code